# Duplicate without user selected canonical, even though pages are different. Why?

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

I am using the Search Console and I encountered this problem with my Angular 7 app for a webshop. At first, I thought it was a Javascript rendering problem, but made sure all server resources were ready when loading the page.

However, Google sees multiple pages from different product categories as a duplicate for the main page. I ran the inspect tool and the live test tool and found that the screenshots of the pages were different as they should normally be.

Thus I don't understand why Google still sees them as duplicates. I figured it might something due to the time Google takes for indexing, but Google tells me that their last crawl was after I asked for new indexing.

What might be the problem?

Here are the two pages:

[image]

[image]

Here is the screenshot from Google Search Console:

[image]